# Permissions confusion - one drive for business

Tags: permissions, office365, onedrive, sharepoint-online, sitecollection

I am trying to figure out why I have access to everyone's files within ODFB as the owner and have come to a dead end.

I thought it was because I was a global admin but their are 6 other users who are also global admins.

When a user adds a file to their ODFB or creates a new file they show they are shared with 'Only you' on their computer, however I am also listed as the owner

[image]

The user has in no way shared this document with me. so I digged deeper...

It turns out I am the site collection administrator for every user account in the our tenant 
[image]

We have hundreds of users and I certainly have not gone through one by one adding myself as the site collection administrator.

Is it because I am named as a site collection administrator for my.sharepoint.com? but if that was the case wouldn't company administrator also be listed as an owner on every users files in ODFB.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should not happen, even if you are a site collection admin you should not be able to view other people's files unless they shared it with you.

ODFB is hosted in o365, so if you are an owner of the site where they drop their files to, definitely you have access for all site contents and this is what is happening in your case.

If users drops files in their o365 drive, you should not be able to view it.

Comment: Thanks for the response - everything I read so far also pointed to the same conclusion, we did a test and created a file directly in a users ODFB folder, I had access to that file straight away. I am sure there is an explanation to it but for the time being it is so bizarre to me that this is happening

Comment: glad it helps @Jamie_lee